# Элемент страницы обновляется только после второго нажатия

Tags: javascript, html, django, события

Почему элемент страницы обновляется только после второго нажатия и как это исправить

```
<span id="balance">
    Баланс: {{ profile.money }}$
</span>
<div id="button" onclick="isClicked()">
    <img src="/media/images/click.png">
</div>
```

```
function isClicked(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8000/add-money/');
    request.responseType = 'text';
    request.onload = function() {
        toText = request.response;
    }

    request.send();

    var text = document.getElementById('balance');
    text.innerHTML = toText;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Используйте `POST` для изменения состояния; `GET` -- для запроса состояния
2. `toText = request.response` в `onload`, запустится он после `text.innerHTML = toText`
3. `toText` -- глобальная переменная, неопределенная, с неограниченным сроком жизни. Старайтесь использовать `const`, реже `let`, в максимально узком скопе.

Comment: На счёт второго пунтка. А как сделать так, чтобы функция request.onload запускалась первее?

Comment: если по-быстрому, то переставьте всё, что после `send` внутрь `onload`; Если по-хорошему, то я бы использовал `fetch`+`await`+`React.useEffect`.

Comment: Благодарю, помог

Comment: всегда рад; голосуйте / принимайте ответ)